# Existing Tkinter Code that Takes an Input String to Another String

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I already posted about this, however, my purpose here is different.  I believe there should be code around that does something very similar to this.  I was hoping someone might have an idea of where to look for examples like this (interfaces of functions that act on strings).  Even better, does anyone have a block of code they already have available?  I'm just looking for a template to base mine off of.  Thanks in advance.

To give you an idea of what I mean, here's the function I have in mind:

```
 def psi_j(x, j):
      rtn = []
      for n2 in range(0, len(x) * j - 2):
        n = n2 / j
        r = n2 - n * j
        rtn.append(j * x[n] + r * (x[n + 1] - x[n]))
        print 'n2 =', n2, ': n =', n, ' r =' , r, ' rtn =', rtn
      return rtn
```

This code takes a string x = [0,1,1,1,2] for example (it must always begin with 0) and a parameter j, say 2, and outputs a string (x = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3] in this example).

It does this in two steps: First it decomposes some number m into a multiple of j and a remainder.  Then it runs this decomposition through a function on the rtn.append line.

Notice that this has cj - 1 terms where c is the number of terms in the input string and j is the parameter.  Normally, we would like it to be able to calculate cj terms.  This is an issue with the function that I am more than happy to put aside for the moment.

My key interest is to be able to make this program usable for someone who has no knowledge of programming.  In particular, I need some kind of user interface that prompts the user to input a string (ideally just by putting in numbers in the form 011123334 for example) and a parameter.

EDIT:

The error is on the third line, and python highlights the space to the right of (self, master) in orange all the way to the end of the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in making a user interface of this with Tkinter you can use the following code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.entryLabel = Label(self, text="Please enter a list of numbers (no commas):")
        self.entryLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.listEntry = Entry(self)
        self.listEntry.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=E)

        self.entryLabel = Label(self, text="Please enter an index value:")
        self.entryLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=E)

        self.indexEntry = Entry(self)
        self.indexEntry.grid(row=1, column=2)

        self.runBttn = Button(self, text="Run Function", command=self.psiFunction)
        self.runBttn.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.answerLabel = Label(self, text="Output List:")
        self.answerLabel.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

    def psiFunction(self):
        j = int(self.indexEntry.get())
        valueList = list(self.listEntry.get())
        x = map(int, valueList)
        if x[0] != 0:
            x.insert(0, 0)
        rtn = []
        for n2 in range(0, len(x) * j - 2):
            n = n2 / j
            r = n2 - n * j
            rtn.append(j * x[n] + r * (x[n + 1] - x[n]))
        self.answer = Label(self, text=rtn)
        self.answer.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

If you have any questions let me know; this works in python 2.7.

This program automatically adds a zero if the user forgets to and the format for input is, for example, 01112.

You can use `rtn` later on as well; it is a list of results.

Comment: This looks great Al - exactly what I was looking for.  I'm quite new to Tkinter so I will have to take a minute to play around and make sure I can make everything run smoothly.

Comment: Hi Al, I do seem to get an error when I try to run it from the terminal.  Nothing happens when I run it from IDLE either but I understand that's because IDLE gets confused about root.mainloop().

Comment: Further, is there a way to create a .exe file from it?  A link will do, I'm very grateful for your response.

Comment: I would check out [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) to make an executable from it.

Comment: And actually, you can make it work with IDLE! When I'm testing out code, I use IDLE very often. Thing is, you don't need the IDLE shell. When you open IDLE, open a new window (it should be a blank page.) Add the code into that, making sure you indent correctly, and hit F5. It will prompt you to save; make sure you append whatever name you chose with ".py".

Comment: Thanks!  And I should be able to get it to run just from there?  I've tried running it that way in IDLE and in the terminal and I can't seem to get it to work. I've appended my original post with the changed indentation (other members told me I might want to try indenting this way) but so far I've had no luck.  When I try to run python filname.py it tells me 'invalid syntax'.  Any ideas?

Comment: For now don't worry about terminal. Just open new IDLE documents (there won't be any `>>>`s) and run them with F5. Does that work?

Comment: It seems like it should, though it told me there was a syntax error. I've edited my post to clarify.  I think it might be an issue with trailing white space but I tried 'remove trailing white space' and the same error came up.

Comment: If I had to guess (and based on your other posts) you do have indentation errors.

Comment: You're absolutely right I found the error.  Sorry about the goose chase.

Comment: Is there a way to make the program work for, say, [0,1,2,3,4] with parameter, say, 4?  That would make for 17 terms including 0 in the output and it would look like 012345678910111213141516.  Right now I get errors when I try to increase beyond index 2.

Comment: I will actually make another question to prevent crowding.